# pagination in rails 3 for definitions in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application I need to display a large number of outputs, by using will_paginate. But  since the controller code calls a definition which is defined in models I cant use pagination since the condition to fetch the queries is defined in my models. 
My models file

```
class Tweets<ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :id, :tweet_created_at, :tweet_id, :tweet_text, :tweet_source, :user_id, :user_name, :user_sc_name, :user_loc, :user_img, :longitude, :latitude, :place, :country
  def self.for_coordinates(coordinates)
    bbox = { min_lat: coordinates.latitude - 1.0, max_lat: coordinates.latitude + 1.0,
      min_lng: coordinates.longitude - 1.0, max_lng: coordinates.longitude + 1.0
    }
    Tweets.where("(longitude BETWEEN ? and ?) AND (latitude BETWEEN ? and ?) OR (user_loc LIKE ?) " ,
                 bbox[:min_lng], bbox[:max_lng], bbox[:min_lat], bbox[:max_lat], "%#{coordinates.city}%" )

  end

  def self.for_user_location(city)
    @tweets= Tweets.where("user_loc LIKE ?", "%#{city}%")
  end
end
```

My code for the controller

```
class TweetsController<ApplicationController
  def index
    city = params[:show]
    search_term = params[:text]
    search_term.gsub!(/\s/, '%')
    city_coordinates = Coordinates.where('city=?', city)
    if (city_coordinates.count == 1 && city_coordinates.first.valid_location?)
      @tweets = Tweets.for_coordinates(city_coordinates.first) & Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE?" , "%#{search_term}%")  
    elsif (city_coordinates.count != 1 )
      @tweets = Tweets.for_user_location(city) &  Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE?" , "%#{search_term}%")  
    else
      Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE? ", "%#{search_term}%").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
    end
  end
end
```

Since the controller is calling a definition which is defined in the model I am stuck up with this to use pagination  using will_paginate. Any help please?

Comment: You can call `paginate` on `ActiveRelation` objects and `Array`s. It doesnt matter whether they come from a `Model` definition

Comment: should I use scopes in models and call them using pagination in controllers or can I call it directly?

Comment: You can call it directly.

Comment: but it says "undefined method "'params' "  for 'class' in models file. is there any method by which I can use params in models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call paginate on the results, not in the `Model`

```
(Tweets.for_coordinates(city_coordinates.first) & Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE?" , "%#{search_term}%")).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
```

You will have to call `require 'will_paginate/array'`

Comment: I tried that also it says undefined method 'paginate' for array for line 13 in tweets_controller.rb

Comment: Just add this to your controller `require 'will_paginate/array'`

Comment: ya sorry forgot to click on that. By the way my code is working perfectly but its taking a very long time to load the results.I am using WEBrick server with ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.13. I am sure if it is this slow rails framework would have been wiped away. Could you help me what is the reason?

Comment: I think you should leave out the `&` and fire a single query which include both the conditions, and call paginate on that. This will save a lot of memory.

Comment: I will try that. for searching text  by using solr/sphinx or sunspot will it help ? the logic is in such a way that I have implement  two conditions for which I have to rip it into two queries. Will using the full text search   gem help?

Comment: Thanks a lot . it works much faster when i fire as a single query. On a side note I would like to ask  this. I have been asked to develop this application using rails ,is it faster and more secure than just using php-mysql without any php framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

*controller:*

```
Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE? ","%#{search_term}%").page(params[:page]).per(50)
```

*view*

```
<%= paginate @tweets %>
```